# Why doesn't work logging in my springboot app on aws elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My war application deployed on aws elasticbeanstalk doesn't write any logs.
I have the same problem like [Logs not working on Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481718/logs-not-working-on-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat-environment). For tests and simplification I deployed  a new empty war project generated from Spring framework Initializr (https://start.spring.io/) built by maven on OpenJDK Java11 to Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.1.1.

I use slf4j logger.
And some info level logs records. On localhost works fine.

On aws elb is /var/log/tomcat/catalina.2020-11-05.log log file and after start I can see only this logs :

```
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.902 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.56
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.906 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 23 2020 17:39:13 UTC
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.56.0
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.14.192-147.314.amzn2.x86_64
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.8+10-LTS
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Amazon.com Inc.
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat
05-Nov-2020 10:48:37.914 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.025 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.078 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.118 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1766 ms
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.263 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.56
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.289 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
05-Nov-2020 10:48:38.738 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
05-Nov-2020 10:48:41.253 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Nov-2020 10:48:41.544 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [3,252] ms
05-Nov-2020 10:48:41.552 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Nov-2020 10:48:41.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3467 ms
```

There is missing my info logs or any other springboot logs from my app.
In previous versions of ELB on java 1.8 it works fine. What has been changed?
How can I turn on logging again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was problem in our java spring application. Wrong devel configuration.
In application.properties was this line

> logging.file.name=log/synchronization.log

I didn't notice that at first sight. In application-production.properties wasn't anything about logging therefore this configuration affected production, and all logs was written to this file (wrong path because on aws eb(tomcat) is directory for logging logs/ not log/). That's why I cannot see logs on standard log path less /var/log/tomcat/

I changed in application-production.properties to

> logging.file.name=logs/my-app.log

and that is. It works now.